# Should we reroute duplicates if a better fit emerges?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I was trying to decide between `babel` and `polyglossia` for use with LuaLaTeX, so I googled "babel vs polyglossia". The first result is the somewhat outdated question [Decide between Polyglossia and Babel in 2012](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88481/decide-between-polyglossia-and-babel-in-2012), the second one is [Babel or Polyglossia with LuaLatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303389/babel-or-polyglossia-with-lualatex?noredirect=1&lq=1) from 2016, which is marked as a duplicate of the first. The much more current question [Decide between Polyglossia and Babel for LuaLaTeX in 2019](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482396/decide-between-polyglossia-and-babel-for-lualatex-in-2019) does not appear on the first page of the search results.<sup>1</sup>

Since most people stumbling on the 2016 question nowadays are certainly looking for the 2019 question rather than the 2016 one, should we change it to be a duplicate of the latter? What would be the process for doing so?

<sub><sup>1</sup>I am aware that more refined search queries do turn up the 2019 question, but that is not the point of this question.</sub>

Comment: I think the duplicate target can be changed by the site moderators (Joseph Wright, Martin Scharrer and Stefan Kottwitz). But an easier solution may be to edit both the 2012 and the 2016 question by adding comments such as the one you posted actually in the question itself on the top, maybe in a quote block to give it more prominence. Note that the 2019 question is a bit specific for LuaTeX, so it may not be the best duplicate target for the two other questions.

Comment: Duplicate targets can also be changed by user with gold tag badge.

Comment: @Marijn I think posting a comment at the top of question would be more confusing than helpful, as there would be two conflicting boxes at the top of the question, one of which is uncommon. A new or additional target of the duplication notice would be much better. I tried flagging it for moderator attention some days ago but nothing came of it.

Comment: @Marijn I agree that the 2012 question is not a duplicate of the 2019 question, but the 2016 question is also specific to LuaTeX and, I think, a rather clear duplicate of the 2019 one.